# Limit camera rotation on the Y axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using [JSModeler](https://github.com/kovacsv/JSModeler) to display `OBJ` files. It internally uses `THREE.JS` and creates a `PerspectiveCamera`. What I need is to limit the movement of the camera on the Y axis so not to go underneath the object. I know how to do this with `THREE.OrbitControls` but this doesn't work with `JSModeler`. Is there a way to directly control the camera movement? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like they use three.js controls. You'd have to find where they manipulate their camera, and inject/interrupt code as appropriate.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks but any ideas where to look at. I see a reference to the PerspectiveCamera but nothing else.

Comment: As @TheJim01 pointed, they do not use THREE.OrbitControls. I would suggest you to have a look at navigation.js (https://github.com/kovacsv/JSModeler/blob/master/src/viewer/navigation.js) to understand it and try to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

jsmodeler creates its own set of controls which it stores in JSM.navigation object.

```
viewer = new JSM.ThreeViewer ();
camera_object = viewer.navigation.camera
```

The drawLoop function takes in values in this `viewer.navigation.camera` and renders them on the canvas. So, suppose if you change the values in the `viewer.navigation.camera`, and call `drawCallback()`, the changes would get rendered.

```
  viewer.navigation.camera.eye.x = 1; // Any value you want
  viewer.navigation.camera.eye.y = 1; // Any value you want
  viewer.navigation.camera.eye.z = 1; // Any value you want
  viewer.navigation.drawCallback();
```